# How to deal with deleted message types in bag migration?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag with a topic that is no longer used, which uses a type which is no longer used. `rosbag check` will interpret this as a moved message type, and prompt me to enter the new location of the message type.

If instead of moving this message type, I just want to ignore this message type, is there a way to do this? I realize I could use `rosbag filter` if necessary to remove this topic beforehand, but if there's another solution that doesn't involve creating an extra bag in the middle, I'd prefer that solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238468/how-to-deal-with-deleted-message-types-in-bag-migration?/) by [juesato](https://answers.ros.org/users/27184/juesato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One semantically-correct way to do this would be to migrate the message into a `std_msgs/Empty`, but this (annoyingly) results in a syntax error in some generated python code. I've found that migrating the message to a `std_msgs/Bool` seems to work okay.

---

Originally posted by [bwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/27399/bwr/) with karma: 26 on 2016-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1